# How do I make the streamWriter write a new file in the same folder C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, textbox, streamwriter

I have 3 forms.. Only 2 which I am using.
The registerForm, loginForm and mainForm.

This is how everything is set up.

Application opens and prompts the user with the login form > User can either log in to a existing account or press register > user logs in > streamWriter creates a text file with the users username and password > textfile stores at 
("C:\" + regUsernametextBox.Text + "\infoBox.creds"). Keep in mind that the ("infoBox.creds") is just an extension that I made.

User can type stuff into the mainForm's textbox which is called textBox1

I want the streamWriter to write a textfile of the content that is inside of the textBox1 into the same folder as the user credentials are.

#### Example

I create a user named Tom > The application creates a folder names Tom with a textfile in it, and that textfile contains the username and password of the user.

When the user that is logged in writes something in the textBox1 I want it to save that text to another textfile but in the same folder which would be the "Tom" folder.

#### What I have tried

What I have done (as you can see below) is that i've tried storing the value of the username from the loginForm and tried using that value in my mainForm

> Giving the file a name

```
var streamWrite = new System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\\" + loginFrm.folderName + "\\Conent.info");
```

And then storing the value in it

```
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\" + loginFrm.folderName);
    var streamWrite = new System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\\" + loginFrm.folderName + "\\Conent.info");
    streamWrite.Write(textboxContent);
```

But it doesnt write a textfile with the information that has been given to the textBox1 in the mainForm.

I hope I described my issue well and I appriciate any help possible!

> mainForm Code

```
public partial class mainForm : MetroForm
{
    public mainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public string textboxContent;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textbox1.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.SavedText;
        loginForm loginFrm = new loginForm();
        loginFrm.Hide();
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        loginForm loginFrm = new loginForm();
        textboxContent = textbox1.Text;
        try
        {
            var streamWrite = new System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\\" + loginFrm.folderName + "\\Conent.info");
            streamWrite.Write(textboxContent);
            streamWrite.Close();
        }
        catch(System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException ex)
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\" + loginFrm.folderName);
            var streamWrite = new System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\\" + loginFrm.folderName + "\\Conent.info");
            streamWrite.Write(textboxContent);
            streamWrite.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Nope");

        }
```

> loginForm Code

```
        public loginForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string username, password;
        public string folderName;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
                folderName = username;
                var sr = new System.IO.StreamReader("C:\\" + regUsernametextBox.Text + "\\infoBox.creds");
                username = sr.ReadLine();
                password = sr.ReadLine();
                sr.Close();

                if(username == regUsernametextBox.Text && password == regPasswordTextBox.Text)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("You have successfully logged in", "Authorize");

                    loginForm regFrm = new loginForm();
                    this.Hide();
                    mainForm mainFrm = new mainForm();
                    mainFrm.ShowDialog();
                    this.Show();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please make sure you typed int he correct name and password", "Authorize Error!");
                }

            }
            catch(System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The user does not exist","Error");
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void registerLinkLabel_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            registerForm regFrm = new registerForm();
            regFrm.Visible = true;


        }
    }
}
```

> registerForm Code

```
        public registerForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void registerForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void registerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\\" + regUsernametextBox.Text + "\\infoBox.creds");
                sw.Write(regUsernametextBox.Text + "\n" + regPasswordTextBox.Text);
                sw.Close();
            }
            catch(System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException ex)
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\" + regUsernametextBox.Text);
                var sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\\" + regUsernametextBox.Text + "\\infoBox.creds");
                sw.Write(regUsernametextBox.Text + "\n" + regPasswordTextBox.Text);
                MessageBox.Show("Account successfully created!","Account");
                sw.Close();
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Firstly, thank you for posting your question with supporting code.  When you say that no file is being written, is there an exception being raised?  If so please add details of it to the question.  There may be an issue with creating folders from the c:\ folder.  There are MS guidelines on where to create application files and typically you would use a call to Environment.GetFolderPath to return an appropriate folder.  There are a few other improvements that we can make to your code but let's fix it first.

Comment: @OldBoyCoder Ther eare no exceptions being thrown, I've even run through it mutiple times with the debugger with breakpoints aswell, I cant seem to find the issue.

Comment: @VargaDev does it work with the `infoBox.creds` file? is this one saved correctly?

Comment: @MongZhu Yes, that one works perfectly

Comment: @VargaDev alright, then it sounds like the `null` problem in `loginForm` did you try my edit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your `mainForm` is closing

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    loginForm loginFrm = new loginForm();
```

Your create a new loginForm, Which is blank and the value `loginFrm.folderName` should be `null` or an empty string (I don't see the constructor of `loginForm`).

You need the original reference of the `loginForm` with the entered data, or at least the `folderName`.

So in your `mainForm` create a variable that can catch the folder name

```
public partial class mainForm : MetroForm
{
    public string User_folder_Name;
```

When you call the `mainForm` in the `loginForm` pass first the value:

```
mainForm mainFrm = new mainForm();

mainFrm.User_folder_Name = folderName;

mainFrm.ShowDialog();
```

And now you can use it in the closing event of your `mainForm`.
I would also suggest using a "using" block.

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    loginForm loginFrm = new loginForm();
    textboxContent = textbox1.Text;
    // Path.Combine is a conmfortable tool to create paths
    string completeFolderPath = Path.Combine(@"C:\", User_folder_Name);
    string completeFIlePath = Path.Combine(completeFolderPath, "Conent.info");


    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(completeFIlePath))
    {   // check whether the directory exists and create on if NOT
        if (!Directory.Exists(completeFolderPath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(completeFolderPath);
            MessageBox.Show("Directory created");

        }
        // write the content
        streamWrite.Write(textboxContent);
    }    
}
```

**EDIT:**

in your `loginForm` you have the three variables

```
public string username, password;
public string folderName;
```

when the form is created with the `new` keyword. All those values are `null` in the beginning, because you don't assign explicitly values to them.

In the button click event you do this:

```
folderName = username;
```

which is basically assigning a variable which is `null` to another variable which is also `null`. So the result is `null`
when you then read the file you fill only `username` but the value is never passed to `foldername`, which is still `null`.

Please exchange the order of the two lines. like this:

```
var sr = new System.IO.StreamReader("C:\\" + regUsernametextBox.Text + "\\infoBox.creds");
username = sr.ReadLine();
password = sr.ReadLine();

folderName = username;
sr.Close();
```

Comment: Well spotted.  One of the observations I was going to make was to say to hold the foldername as a field within mainForm rather than relying on loginForm still being around.

Comment: @OldBoyCoder I'm still not seeing the issue.. Does he mean that when I call the loginForm on the closing event, its empty, theres nothing there?

Comment: Yes because you're explicitly creating a new instance of the form.  The one you created in Form1_Load will have been destroyed because it only existed within the scope of that method.  I'd create a new proerty of mainForm called 'loginFolderName'  In Form1_load do 'loginFolderName = loginfrm.foldername'.  Then in the closing method just use loginFolderName rather than loginfrm.foldername.

Comment: @VargaDev as I see it you call in `loginForm` after the button has been clicked a new `mainForm` and then in the `mainForm` you create an entirely new instance of `loginForm` (like a new white sheet of paper), but you need the old paper which is already written on. or at least the information on it. That's why before taking the new `mainForm` sheet write the old information onto it before exposing it with `show`

Comment: @MongZhu When I try to combine the two paths at " string completeFolderPath = Path.Combine(@"C:\", User_folder_Name); "
it says Value cannot be null. as an error
https://i.gyazo.com/8eca6e5146904487abc0ef3aa978a65f.png

Comment: @MongZhu Doesnt look like I forgot to add a value to the user_Name variable atleast so not sure why its null

Comment: @MongZhu Thank you for explaining so well, I've learned alot of new stuff today!

Comment: @VargaDev Yeah I know that feeling :) glad I could be of help